# Flutter I have two periodic Timer only once works

Tags: flutter, dart, module, timer

I would like to create a separate periodic timer for each statefull module that repeatedly calls certain functions.

First this stateful Widget here it works the Timer:

```
 class Wetteddaten extends StatefulWidget{
  const Wetteddaten({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  WetterdatenContent createState() => WetterdatenContent();
}
```

Extends State:

```
class WetterdatenContent extends State {
   WetterdatenContent() {
/*
  var periodicTimer = Timer.periodic(
    const Duration(seconds: 5),
        (timer) {

      // Update user about remaining time
      _getLocation();
    },
  );*/
}
```

This ist in Comments but _getLocation() runs

But in this Modul periodic Timer dosent work:

```
class getPositionAdress extends StatefulWidget{
  const getPositionAdress({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AdressCalc createState() => AdressCalc();
}
```

In Adress Class

```
class AdressCalc extends State {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) {

      _updateState();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  AdressCalc() {
    var counter = 3;

}
```

It makes no difference whether the timer is in initState or AdressCalc().

I have no idea what could be causing this.
Also updateState is executed after and before the timer but not inside

My project idea is to create a weather app with three separate stateful modules, each of which has its own periodic timer that controls the module and monitors whether something has changed in the variable values.
The Main Modul is a Sateless Widget

Comment: How did you conclude that the periodic `Timer` isn't working?  Exactly what happens?  If you put a `debugPrint` statement within the `Timer` callback, do you not see any output printed to the console?

Comment: Yes you are right the timer is running.

The problem lies somewhere else. On the one hand, I don't always get the debug output displayed with my Android Studio.

But the real problem is I guess.

How do I update the build widget regularly when there is a change.
I output a text widget which is probably only filled once with the init value and is then no longer updated.
`child: Text(test, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, textAlign: TextAlign.center),` `  void _updateState() {

    test = "update"+counter.toString();
    geodata = globals.placemarks;
    counter++;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. For one, the main widget was stateless must be stateful.

On the other hand I have included a  ValueNotifier

Which change the value of Text field.